# Streamwriter set true stil overwrites csv lines

Tags: c#, streamwriter

i need to read and write data into a csv file. In the first line of my csv there's a number that i am raising with every new data. The following lines contain information about persons starting with an individual number. I need to read the first line and convert it to a number so i can rewrite it for the added line. Next problem is when I overwrite the number is the first line the StreamWriter (set on true) does overwrite line two but it should add a line at the end of the file. Example:

```
Line1: 2345 
Line2: 2343    John   Smith       01.01.1999 
Line3: 2344   Dave   Mustane     02.02.2000 
Line4: 2345    Linda  Fisher     03.03.1995
```

And this is my code:

```
using System.IO;

private void btn_speichern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dateipfad = @"C:\test";
    string input;
    int ID = 0;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dateipfad))
        input = reader.ReadLine() ?? "";

    try
    {
        ID = Int32.Parse(input);
        ID = ++ID;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error - cannot convert ID");
    }

    using (StreamWriter newid = new StreamWriter(dateipfad))
    {
        newid.WriteLine(ID);
        newid.Flush();
    }  //This is how I write the lines:

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dateipfad, true))
    {
        string row = string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-30}{2,-30}{3,-10}", ID, tbName.Text, tbVorname.Text, tbTag.Text + "." + tbMonat.Text + "." + tbJahr.Text);

        writer.WriteLine(row);

        MessageBox.Show("Erfolg!");

    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not the `true` argument there where you try to appending a new row. The new row will be appended to the file just fine. But pay attention to your code and look a few lines above. Look at the code block where you do `using (StreamWriter newid = new StreamWriter(dateipfad)) { newid.WriteLine(ID); ... } `. Explain to yourself what that code block does exactly. Use the documentation to verify your explanation. If unsure, use the step debugger in Visual Studio, and execute the code in this block step-by-step and watch how the file changes after each code line there is being executed

Comment: (Hint: That code block does not overwrite the number in the first line and leaves the rest of the file intact, as you seem to believe. No, that's not what that code block is actually doing ;-) )

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for the fast answer. I am new to the whole topic.
Actually the Code does overwrite the number in line one. so the number is kinda working. my main problem is that the following writer overwrites line two instead of adding a new line to the csv. Do you have a solution or alternative to put a new line at the end of csv?

Comment: You do not debug properly, and you just assume what's happening without actually verifying your assumptions. Debug step-by-step and verify the state of your file after every single line of code being executed. "_Actually the Code does overwrite the number in line one_". That's not entirely true. Check the content of the file after you seemingly only overwrote the 1st line. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) "_my main problem is that the following writer overwrites line two instead_". Nope, the following (second) writer does not overwrite anything. You made a wrong assumption about what your first writer does, and in consequence you made another wrong assumption what the 2nd writer does. Alternatively to using the debugger, execute your program without using the 2nd writer (the writer where you attempt to append stuff; for testing just comment it out entirely). See what happens. Also, re-visit the documentation for the StreamWriter(string) constructor you are using and read it carefully. ;-)

Comment: Side note: If you are not yet familiar with Visual Studio's awesome step-debugger, Microsoft provides a handy beginner guide: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger)

Comment: Last but not least, i suggest the following approach: load the text file entirely into memory (check the System.IO.File class, it should have one or two methods that should help you, depending on your application scenario). Then manipulate the data in memory. When finished with all the data manipulation, dump/write/save the file completely at once into a new file. This approach is much less error-prone... (Make a backup of/rename the original file before saving, so you don't lose it if something goes wrong during saving.)